# Ampliar 2 imagens simultaneamente

Tags: javascript, imagem

Bom dia pessoal,
preciso clicar em 2 imagens e elas devem se abrir lado a lado para que o cliente possa fazer um comparativo do antes e depois.

Observem que estou usando o materialboxed do materialize até ai ok se ele clicar em 1 só imagem, mas quando ele seleciona 2 imagens queria fazer o mesmo efeito...

```
<div class="col s2" style="width: 110px">
    <img src="<?php echo Url::getBase().'img/varizes2.jpg'?>" width="105" class="materialboxed"/>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nem a [documentação](https://materializecss.com/media.html) nem o [código](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/v1-dev/js/materialbox.js) especificam que é necessário que o HTML seja um `<img>`.

Então você pode simplesmente criar um container e aplicar o plugin no container ao invés das imagens.

Exemplo:

```js
$('.compare').materialbox();
```

```css
.compare {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
     
<div class="compare">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/fff000/ffffff">
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m2vskya1/5/) funcionando...

Comment: Fernando tinha pensado assim também, mas, acho que o que ele quer é no clique do check abre as imagens, não sei, parece que é isto!

Comment: Mas se for isso que ele quer é só ver a documentação e ativar usando método `.open()`. Acho que essa não seria uma grande barreira.. espero..

Comment: Fernando, obrigado pela resposta, ainda não é assim amigo, e como o LeAndrade falou, eu irei "checar 2" imagens e terei um terceiro botão digamos assim que ao clicar neste terceiro botão as duas imagens checadas iriam abrir igual ao slider ai mesmo... consegui ser claro? valeu

Comment: Hmmm.. então as imagens dentro do `materialbox` serão dinâmicas? Vai depender do input do usuário?

Comment: Sim, serão dinamicas, mas estarão salvas em um bd...